# Appling div class based filters

Tags: javascript

I have a form - which allows the user to select an option from a dropdown

```html
<form action="/create_tasks/" name="form2" , id="form2" method="post" class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center">
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="F9Xrs4SIcjDS3yVMCH1hbAB1p3encpExp14ynCZV5jsDgjcD41qFoVeDn4wtpGr8">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label class="visually-hidden" for="inlineFormSelectPref">Preference</label>
    <select class="form-select" id="inlineFormSelectPref">
      <option selected value='all'>All </option>
      <option value=SQL>SQL</option>
      <option value=Apache Spark>Apache Spark</option>
      <option value=Python>Python</option>
      <option value=Linux>Linux</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">filter</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I have divs underneath like this:

```
<div class="card mb-2 sh-10 sh-md-8 Python ">
</div>
<div class="card mb-2 sh-10 sh-md-8 Python ">
</div>
```

If the user selects a value from the dropdown, i want to only show the divs with that class (e.g. select Python , only show python divs). If they select 'all' I want to show them all

I had a play with some options but i cant make it work. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Can you share what have you tryed so far?

Comment: Ive tried following this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp - but I am not sure how to dynamically pass in the form value to hide or show it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `input` event listener on your `select` field. This will trigger every time you change option in your `select`. When this event trigger, simply read `select` value and show divs accordingly.

```js
const select = document.getElementById('select');
const showSelected = name => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.form-option').forEach(card => {
        card.style.display = name === 'all' ? 'block' : 'none';
        if (name !== 'all' && card.classList.contains(name.replace(' ', '-'))) {
            card.style.display = 'block';
        }
    });
}

showSelected('all');
select.addEventListener('input', () => {
    showSelected(select.value);
});
```

```html
<select id="select">
    <option selected value='all'>All</option>
    <option value="SQL">SQL</option>
    <option value="Apache Spark">Apache Spark</option>
    <option value="Python">Python</option>
    <option value="Linux">Linux</option>
</select>

<div class="form-option SQL">SQL</div>
<div class="form-option Apache-Spark">Apache Spark</div>
<div class="form-option Python">Python</div>
<div class="form-option Linux">Linux</div>
```